# .SVG image looks different on different computers

Tags: css, svg

Why would a .svg image look different on different computers? 
Image A and B are both on Windows 10 machines, using the latest build of Chrome (49) yet they are rendered differently.
I used Inkscape to create the image. Its just text that says `<code>`, and then some shapes used for the face inside the 'O'
Here is the code on the style sheet for it:

```css
body {
 
 background-color: #add8e6;
background-image:url(https://arges86.homeserver.com/How_To//img/Code_Icon.svg), url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background-position: right center, left top;
background-attachment: fixed;

background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
}
```

[Image A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdKWR.png)

[Image B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDH5H.png)

Any thoughts would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps Image A doesn't have the required font installed?

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Is this something that could be fixed with an '@font-face'?
And if so, would that go in the style sheet or the html document?

Comment: If it were to go anywhere it'd go in the CSS, before the `body` rule. I'm not sure if it will work but it's worth a shot